# Can't bind DependencyProperties from UserControl code behind to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a UserControl in my WPF project which I want should have a DependencyProperty that I can bind to in the parent. The project is written as MVVM and I'm using Caliburn micro.

I really want to write clean and maintainable code using MVVM, so I want my UserControls to utilize viewmodels as much as possible and code behind as little as possible.

The problem is that I'm unsuccessful in getting the binding between the parent and the UserControl viewmodel to work correctly.

MyUserControl:

```cs
    public partial class MyUserControlView : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControlView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // If no Datacontext is set, binding between parent property and textbox text works - one way only (set from parent)!.
            // -
    
            // If Datacontext is set to this, bindings with properties in MyUserControlView code behind works.
            //DataContext = this;
    
            // If Datacontext is set to MyUserControlViewModel, binding between MyUserControlViewModel and MyUserControlView works, but not with parent.
            DataContext = new MyUserControlViewModel();
        }
    
        public string ProjectNumber
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyUserControlValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyUserControlValueProperty, value); }
        }
    
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyUserControlValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ProjectNumber", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControlView), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnProjectNumberUpdate)));
    
        private static void OnProjectNumberUpdate(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var view = d as MyUserControlView;
            view.ProjectNumberText.Text = e.NewValue as string;
        }
    }
```

MyUserControl code behind:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="In MyUserControl: " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectNumber}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="ProjectNumberText" Text="{Binding ProjectNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

MyUserControl ViewModel:

```cs
public class MyUserControlViewModel : Screen
{
    private string _projectNumber;

    public string ProjectNumber
    {
        get { return _projectNumber; }
        set
        {
            _projectNumber = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProjectNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Parent view:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyUserControlView ProjectNumber="{Binding ParentProjectNumber}" />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="In parent: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentProjectNumber}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Parent ViewModel:

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        ParentProjectNumber = "Hello from parent!";
    }

    private string _parentProjectNumber;

    public string ParentProjectNumber
    {
        get { return _parentProjectNumber; }
        set
        {
            _parentProjectNumber = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ParentProjectNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

I know I'm probably way off here, but I have no idea what to do to get the bindings to work correctly.

Is there a better way to bind between a DependencyProperty and a viewmodel? Can I put the DP in the viewmodel somehow?

Here is the entire project solution: https://github.com/ottosson/DependencyPropertyTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't change UserControl.DataContext from inside UserControl. it can and *will* create issues later.

use proper name for DP (ProjectNumberProperty and corresponding ProjectNumber) and add BindsTwoWayByDefault to metadata:

```
public partial class MyUserControlView : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ProjectNumber
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ProjectNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProjectNumberProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        "ProjectNumber", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(MyUserControlView), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
    );
}
```

fix bindings in xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="In MyUserControl: " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectNumber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ProjectNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

that should do it.

btw, "clean and maintainable code using MVVM" and "want my UserControls to utilize viewmodels as much as possible" sort of contradict each other.

also nothing wrong with code-behind in UserControls as long as that code handles only view functionality. for example: [DataGrid source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs) contains 8000+ LoC

Comment: Thanks. I agree that everything doensn't have to be in a ViewModel. The example was simplified for the question. However, did I miss something? My question was about how I could bind between a viewmodel and dependency properties and I don't see any connection to the viewmodel in your answer?

Comment: the connection with vm is here: `<local:MyUserControlView ProjectNumber="{Binding ParentProjectNumber}" />`. it remains the same. you need to fix MyUserControlView for it to work

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear about it, but I want a viewmodel for my usercontrol. I need to do a bunch of input validation which I thought would fit nicely in the child VM not the parent VM.

Comment: then expose child VM in parent VM class. `class ParentVM { public ChildVM ChildVMInstance {get;set;} }`. change binding `local:MyUserControlView ProjectNumber="{Binding ChildVMInstance.ProjectNumber}" />`. that is your viewmodel for usercontrol. creating viewmodels inside usercontrol breaks mvvm. heirarchy of views (nested views) requires hierarchy of view models (nested viewmodels)